# Issue substituting a range variable (Excel VBA)

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble substituting the range variable `WeekdayRule` in my code. The third line of code works just fine. The fourth line of code below triggers an

> application-defined or object-defined error '1004'.

What am I missing here?

```
    Dim WeekdayRule As Range
    Set WeekdayRule = ActiveSheet.Range("M17:O112")

    ActiveSheet.Range("M17:O112").FormatConditions.Delete

    With ActiveSheet.Range("WeekdayRule").FormatConditions _
        .Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND(M17<=($N$8*$V17), $V17>=$N$9)")
        .Interior.ColorIndex = 44
    End With
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.WeekdayRule.FormatConditions` use this and get rid of _ at the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

WeekdayRule is already a defined Range object, so use:

```
WeekdayRule.FormatConditions.Delete
With WeekdayRule.FormatConditions _
...
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the index of the **FormatConditions** collection in order to specify which **FormatCondition** (note singular) object you want to delete. For example:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("M17:O112").FormatConditions(index).Delete
```

Comment: This is not the actual issue. Firstly he said that this line of code is working well. Secondly you don't need to specify the index if you want to delete *all* FormatConditions and therefore the plural is right.